# Using as a graph database for finding "friends" of "friends" in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, graph-databases

I have been investigating a graph database and I have found neo4j and although this seems ideal I have also come across Mongodb.

Mongodb is not an official graph database but I wondered if it could be used for my scenario.

I am writing an application where users can have friends and those friends can have friends etc, the typical social part of a social network.

I was wondering in my situation whether Mongodb might suffice. How easy would it be to implement or do I really need to focus on REAL graph databases?

I do notice foursquare are using Mongodb so I presume it supports their infrastructure.

But how easy would it be to find all friends of my friends that also have friends in common, for example?

Comment: mongodb cannot compete with a real graph db on this

Comment: The reason foursquare uses MongoDB is likely that their application deals a lot with geographical information. MongoDB is a good fit for this, because of its [geospatial indexing and querying feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/). It is the only database I know which has query operators especially for searching by GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it wouldn't be impossible, MongoDB would not be a good fit for this scenario.

The reason is that MongoDB does not do JOINs. When you need a query which spans multiple documents, you need a separate query for each document.

In your example, each `user` document would have an array with the `_id`'s of their friends. To find "all friends of the friends of UserA who are also friends of UserB" would mean that you would:

1. find userA and get his friends-array
2. find all users in that array and get their friend-arrays
3. find all users in these arrays who have UserB in their friends-array

These are three queries you have to perform. Between each of these queries, the result set has to be sent to the application, the application has to formulate a new query and send it back to the database. The result-set returned from the 2nd query can be quite large, which means that the 3rd query could take a while.

**tl;dr:** Use the right tool for the job. When your data is graph-based and you want to do graph-based queries on it, use a graph database.

Comment: @rodi you can run map-reduce to be able to gather data from different collections. But I wouldn't rely on this considering MongoDB runs map-reduce functions with single thread. Better choose Neo4j or another graph db like that for these kind of queries. But still you can combine MongoDB with graph database via replicating your entity data from MongoDB to graph db periodically via Mongo River or sth like that.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want an actual graph database as opposed to MongoDB.  Try using the [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.com) graph technology stack to get started.  Using Blueprints (which is like JDBC for graphs) you can see the performance of MongoDB as a graph (using the [Blueprints MongoDB implementation](https://github.com/datablend/blueprints-mongodb-graph)) versus [Neo4j](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4j-Implementation), [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/), or any number of other graph [implementations](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki).