# Returning parent-child chain in a single mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, directory

I have a filesystem like structure, where there are a bunch of folders that each contain the Object Id of their parent folder. Given a specific folder, I want to return the path to this folder; the only way I can think of to do this is to traverse up the tree of linked Object Ids until I get to the root.

Doing this using just db.find, I would have to send out a number of queries equivalent to the depth of the folder. This doesn't scale however, so I am wondering of there is a way that mongo can chain the connected IDs for me, within a single request. Is this possible? Or is there at least a better way?

Comment: There's a similar question with a good answer here: [MongoDb: Using as a graph database for finding “friends” of “friends” for example?]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894212/mongodb-using-as-a-graph-database-for-finding-friends-of-friends-for-exampl

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a way to do this in a single MongoDB query like you asked for a first.

You could denormalize the path into each object so it doesn't have to walk all the parents. But any changes would require an update to each and every child.

Basically each `folder` has...

```
{
  ...,
  name: "my_folder",
  path: "\path\to\folder", 
  children: ...,
}
```

And when you update a `folder` you need to walk the children of the folder and update them by taking `parent.path`, adding `parent.name`, and slapping that into the child's `path` property. Update away down the chain. Updates are more expensive, but reads a whole lot cheaper.

Comment: Just to clarify, I understood your comment about denormalization before your edit. But the fact is that denormalization of the paths is no better (if not worse) than any other brute force methods of accomplishing this. In terms of scalability, this is simply not feasible.

Comment: Then there is not an acceptable way using MongoDB. A map-reduce query wouldn't make any sense. Select the parent and child records and hope you can put it back together? I'm guessing that scale won't work for you even if it made sense. Now you're just out of options for current MongoDB that doesn't involve solving the problem in your app instead of the DB.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative outside of mongodb then? Are sql databases able to do operations like this? And what about some different model structure other than the child->parent pointers I have now?

Comment: I really just feel like "There is no way to do this" is a lazy answer, because there are clearly many other sites that have found some way to do this.

Comment: They "clearly do" have tree structures but not that for your requirements of a single query unless they denormalize the data. It's a known limitation of this type of data store. It's even pretty complicated in a normal SQL store.

Comment: IMO Storing the full path into each folder is the most efficient.

Whenever you move a folder, or rename, or whatever you'd then have to descend down your tree to change every descendant of that folder.

This would be the optimal solution if the number of changes you make is significantly less than the number of reads.

If you think your folder structure will change quite often, and the structure is anticipated to be quite large and complex, then I would advise on traversing up to root as you've already mentioned in your question...

Comment: You may also think about a caching strategy for paths for each folder, which you can then invalidate if you make changes to an ancestor folder. It is essentially the same as the answer above, but it would be a separate component which you can just switch on or off at will. And the writes will perform just as fast, just the first read will be slower, which if you really don't like can be solved by warming up the cache after a write, which again leads us back to answer by Travis.

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/) has some examples of patterns to model Tree Structures.

Check if one of them fits your requirements. With the information you have provided I would say that an  Array of Ancestors could be a good option.

Comment: The document you linked to is a good resource. It also shows that MongoDB isn't really a good fit for graph or tree-like queries. Looking at the original authors comments, the array of ancestors pattern was not desirable.

Comment: Maybe you can try a graph database like Neo4j. [Here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html) you have an example of an indexing structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you'd like to do is pretty similar to using a tree model.
I understand you data currently don't have the ancestors field, but that would be one of the best approaches to the problem:

```
folder
{    
    _id: 100, 
    folder_name: "foo", 
    ancestors: [80, 23, 1]
}
```

Please check this video from MongoDB University(by 10gen) for further explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=lIjXyQklGWY